# Why live code block from SETUPFILE is not evaluated at export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I would like to execute emacs-lisp code at export time **and** that this code to be defined in another file (using `SETUPFILE`).

Let's consider this two simple files :

- `main.org`

```
#+setupfile: setup.org

Something
```

- `setup.org`

```
#+name: mycode
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :export results :eval yes :results silent
(message "DEBUG")
#+end_src
```

When I try to export `main.org` I thought that the `DEBUG` message should be printed in Emacs Messages which is not the case.

I thought that live code block were evaluated at export which, here, is not the case.

Am I doing something wrongly or did I miss something in the doc?

I am using Emacs 27.1 (from Debian bullseye) and org-mode 9.4 (from elpa).

**Update**: as stated by @NickD in his comment the word `:results` was misspelled in my example. Once corrected everything seems to work correctly when using `#+INCLUDE:` but still not working with `#+SETUPFILE:`.

Comment: You might want to use `#+INCLUDE: ` rather than `#+SETUPFILE: ` in this case.

Comment: I tried before posting the question but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: You might want to fix the code block header: it's `:exports` with an `s`, but `:exports results` and `:results silent` will cancel each other out and produce nothing (maybe last option wins but I have not tested). Try `:exports code` or `:exports both` and lose the `:results silent` if you want the results to be part of the exported output.

Comment: **Thank's a lot!** I effectively misspelled `:exports`. In my example `:exports results` and `:result silent` do not cancel each other since the code has the side effect of writing to the *Messages* buffer.

Comment: By "cancel each other out" I meant that nothing appears in the exported output.

Comment: OK. I still do not understand why it works with `#+INCLUDE:` and not with `#:SETUPFILE:`.

Comment: @db48x's answer below explains why that is. `SETUPFILE` and `INCLUDE` do different things and the paragraph that you found in the manual is wrong. Please report it as a bug with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: Done. @yantar92 proposed a patch.

Answer (score 2):

A 2–minute peek at the source code (the function `org--collect-keywords-1` in `org.el`) reveals that when it sees the `SETUPFILE` keyword, it opens the named file, searches for more keywords in that file, then throws the file away. It doesn’t import the whole file, plonk it in the middle of your org file, and then process all the source blocks in it; it just looks for keywords and nothing else.

You probably read between the lines of the manual and assumed more features than actually exist. The [chapter 13.2 13.2 Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html) of the Org Mode manual says that when there is a `SETUPFILE` keyword it looks in that file for more keywords. That’s it; that’s all it does. It *doesn’t* say that it does anything else with that file.

Comment: Well I read [chapter 17.8 Summary of In-Buffer Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html#index-SETUPFILE_002c-keyword-1) where it is explicitly written that *Org also parses and loads the document during normal exporting process. Org parses the contents of this document as if it was included in the buffer. It can be another Org file.*.

Did I understand it wrongly?

Comment: Huh, I missed that part of the documentation. I see no evidence that it’s true. There’s the code that makes `C-c C-c` open the file for you, and the code that reads settings from it, but nothing else. You might report that as a bug to the maintainers. They have a mailing list.

Comment: Please report that as a bug in the manual with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: Done. @yantar92 proposed a patch.